# how to do validations for numeric,double and empty values for datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

how to do validations for numeric,double and empty values for datagridview in c# windows application.Text values should not be allowed to enter the cells which are numeric or double.how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to validate it when entering or after entered?

Comment: Can you post your code (what have you already done)?

Comment: ojlovecd is right...when do you want to validate you need to tell..

Answer (score 1):

You Can validate datagrid view cell like this...

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
   // Validate the CompanyName entry by disallowing empty strings.
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CompanyName")
    {
        if (e.FormattedValue == null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
          dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
            "Company Name must not be empty";
           e.Cancel = true;
        }
   }
}

void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     // Clear the row error in case the user presses ESC.   
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = String.Empty;
}
```

This validates only empty values , if you want validate numericals you can do like this...
I hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to restrict anything but numbers from being entered, you need to handle the `EditingControlShowing` event on the DataGridView. It can be done like this:

```
dataGridView.EditingControlShowing = new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler (dataGridView_EditingControlShowing);
```

Then, define your handler:

```
    void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing (object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tx = e.Control as TextBox;
        tx.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler (tx_KeyPress_int);
    }
```

Then, define your KeyPress handler, and only handle numeric characters:

```
    void tx_KeyPress_int (object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsNumber (e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b'))
        {
            //is NOT number or is Backspace key
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Adjust to suit your exact needs accordingly (i.e. handle only input on a certain column, etc.)

Comment: And how do you suggest to unsubscribe from KeyPress events?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate cell values when user trying to leave cell, you should handle DataGridView.CellValidating event and process cell value there. 
If you want to validate value when user typing it, you may handle KeyPress event.

To validate numeric values you may use code like this:

```
int number = 0;
if(!int.TryParce(cell.Value.ToString(), out number))
{ 
    //report about error input 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx

@@Edit , 
if you try to use your own custom numeric control, 
1. you no need to check any additional validation.
2. It is reusable.